# Is there a way to save and replay a sequence of shortcut key on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, automation

I'm executing a repetitive series of shortcuts on Windows. Is there a way to save them and "replay" them automatically? 
This is supposed to work Windows-wide as I use multiple software on the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a PowerShell script with the command for sending keys, or you can compile a simple AutoHotkey script.

Comment: With these approaches take a minute to think about what might happen when something hiccups and a hotkey goes to the wrong program/window instead.